# EU cookie compliance

Tags: magento2, module, cookie

I'd like to have a (if possible) free magento 2 extension to deal with EU Cookie Compliance (RGPD).

This module must allow the user to customize it's cookies.

Which one would you recommand ?

Comment: You can try this https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-cookie-notice.html

Comment: I've seen this one, but it doesn't seem to allow the user to customize his cookies

Comment: What type of customization you need?

Comment: maybe you could use this module from Amasty https://amasty.com/cookie-consent-for-magento-2.html (its not free)

Comment: Yeah I would have liked to have a free module. @SukumarGorai i'm not an expert, but I've been given a document with some example of customization. I'm not storing any other cookies than the default cookie of magento (visible in the default page Privacy and Cookie Policy)

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? im looking at the same problem, need to be able to customise their cookies.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, but Magento provides a build-in tool the enable Cookie Compliance (but only "Accept Cookies"). I think the easiest way is to buy one